# Can a Garou create a fetish using bones of another Garou?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

Recently I started a Werewolf table. A Metis Uktena Theurge wants to have a dagger made from his mother's femur. This fetish would be weak (level 2) and the power is still being discussed.

I know that among the Black Spiral Dancers it is common. How would other Garou react to a fetish made of a Garou's bones? Should I allow such an item or should I prevent it? If he creates this item what possible implications and penalties he will suffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Should you allow it?

Bloody Bandages sets a precedent that Garou of the Wyld use their own flesh in crafting Talens/Fetishes without consequences from the spirits.

I don't know a reason to treat a Mother's bone differently, assuming the bone was procured ritualistically in accordance with his Tribe's traditions (mostly handwaveable fluff restriction here, but did he steal the bone or was he allowed to take it?).

On the other hand, I can't source using *another* Garou's remains for a Talen or Fetish, but I see no reason why it would be treated differently, sans customs that the PC would be aware of when creating the item.

## Should there be consequences?

Mostly no.  However, if you decide there should be consequences, then the PC should be given a chance, at character creation, to be aware of those consequences before creating the fetish.  Perhaps a check, perhaps you just tell the player, but it'd be inappropriate for you to rule that his character was not only oblivious to the problem here, but also that it was impossible for him to find it out.

Comment: If you want to draw in the "Hammer and Klaive" it could be very appropriate to assign some kind of taboo/catch associated with the bone. Maybe something along the lines of "only descendants of this bone's lineage".

Comment: Rager - This shard of bone is made from the remains of an Ahroun who fell in combat against the Wyrm.

Comment: Wow, old question, @Scrollreader but I'm entirely unfamiliar with that, so do you have a book?